# Pop image out of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I pop an image out of its div and set its width to 100% (so that it takes up most of the screen)? Note: I don't want to use any plugins.

I have this so far:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="thumbnail_image.png" />
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", ".container img", function(event) {

     /* Get the image name. */
     var src = $(this).attr('src').split('/');
     var file = src[src.length - 1];

     /* Load the big image into the container to replace the thumbnail. */
     $(this).attr('src', 'big_images/' + file);
});
```

How would I do this?

Comment: you can create a jQuery/javascript lightbox, check out this link: http://cssjockey.com/tips/an-easy-way-to-create-light-box-with-jquery-css/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css position fixed. So defining a class like this:

```
.fullscreen_image {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
    width: 100%;
}
```

you can then add and remove this class for your image.

```
$(this).addClass( 'fullscreen_image' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWQds.jpg?s=128&g=1" class="thumbnail"/>
</div>
```

and jquery code:

```
$('#container img').live('click',function(){

$(this).addClass('zoom');

});
```

Check the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sk3zb/) [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sk3zb/)